# RAR - add folders matching specified wildcards?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, rar

I'm using commands line's RAR 5.1 (exe) :

I have this `c:\r\` folder which has :

```
C:\r\
│   MsgProtos.java
│   k.txt
│
├───kjhasd
│       CSharpOptions.cs
│       DescriptorProtoFile.cs
│       kCSharpOptions - Copy.cs
│
└───koio
        CSharpOptions.cs
        DescriptorProtoFile.cs
```

I want to generate an archive file which will include all `k* folders` (starts with k)

- All files in the matching directories should be added !
- The k* filter is only for folder names.

So I should have an archive with

[image]

So I invoked :

`C:\r>rar a myRar# k* -r`

But it shows :

```
Creating archive myRar#.rar

Adding    k.txt
Adding    kjhasd\kCSharpOptions - Copy.cs
Adding    kjhasd
Adding    koio
Done
```

but this doesn't include all files (the yellow ones are missing due to not being `k*`)

[image]

**Question**

What is the right command which will create one archive for all directories which are `k*` ?

Answer (score 1):

> "add **folder** according to wildcards"
>
> "I want to generate an archive file which will include all k*
>   **folders** (starts with k)"
>
> "The k* filter is *only* for **folder** names"

Given your requirements clearly the image below is incorrect, because you've highlighted *k.txt* even though it's not a folder.

[image: 1]

To ensure *kjhasd* (with 3 files) and *koio* (with 2 files) are added completely, make use of the -n matching filter as follows:

```
rar a -n*\k*\* myRar#.rar "C:\r"
```